# Alternative way to use async/await inside the module out of async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Async/await is valid inside the async function so if I have a module where I need to perform async actions that return promises I'm forced to do it like this:

```
import 'systemjs/dist/system';

(async () => {
  await SystemJS.import('module1');
  await SystemJS.import('module2');
  await SystemJS.import('module3')
}());
```

It seems a bit weird to me, but I can't think of any other way to use `async/await`. Is there any? Also, maybe anyone know if there's any proposal that would allow ESM module work as `async` function?

I've just come across [this tweet](https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/912556308649304064) by Addy Osmani where he shows the following code:

```
(async () => {
  const myModule = await import('./myModule.js');
  myModule.foo();
})();
```

so it seems this is the way to go.

Comment: No, IIAFEs are the way to go currently. Using `await` in module top scope was discussed but eventually deferred.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks! Can you point me to the relevant discussion re top level await?

Comment: @Bergi, top level `await` is supported in the Chrome 62 in the console